# Loop to change every 110 lines

Tags: linux, text-processing

I would like to change the time stamps using the current date for every 110 lines of a file. I am using cat on the file and pipe into sed to replace then write to file. Is there a way to just change every 110 lines with the date so that every 110 lines has the current date at time of change? Below is an example of how I currently change a timestamp. This works fine but changes the whole file.

```
cat /path/to/file | sed "s/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{1,2\}\s[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}/$(date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")/g" >> /path/to/newfile
```

I ventured into tail and head to find a solution but the loop below only ever did the first 110

```
i=0
jump=110
while [ $i -le 1100 ]
do
tail -n $i | head -n $jump /path/to/file | sed "s/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{1,2\}\s[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}/$(date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")/g" >> /path/to/newfile
i=$((%i + $jump))
done
```

Here is an example of the input

```
Apr 15 16:29:19 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
```

The output should be the same with the date changed.

```
Apr 1 16:29:19 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001   User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1554103759    TimeWritten=1554103759
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to happen at line 110, 220 etc.  I initially thought you wanted to update every 110th line.  If you want to update the timestamp on _all_ lines, but in chunks of 110 lines at a time, what should happen when a set of 110 lines has been updated? Even a very large file would potentially be processed in under a second, so this requirement seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: Every 110 line batch would have a current timestamp. Example: line 1 -110 has Apr 01 08:10:10 . Line 111 - 221 would be Apr 01 08:10:11 or whatever the time is for the date call.

Comment: I normally expect something like awk to process about 50,000 lines a second. So your timestamp to %S accuracy is probably be changed to the same thing in groups of 50,000 lines, even if we ask the clock every 2 milliseconds and get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you would want to do this, but if you have the GNU version of `split` you could use its `--filter` option to process chunks of the file with your existing `sed` command:

```
split -l 110 file --filter='
  sed "s/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{1,2\}\s[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}/$(date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")/"
' > path/to/newfile
```

To illustrate, I used a shorter (25 line) input file split every 5 lines, and added nanoseconds to the timestamp to ensure the results are visibly different:

```
$ split -l 5 file --filter='
    sed "s/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{1,2\}\s[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}/$(date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S.%N")/"
  '
Apr 01 13:35:36.817804684 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.817804684 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.817804684 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.817804684 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.817804684 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.824106329 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.824106329 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.824106329 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.824106329 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.824106329 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.831402445 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.831402445 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.831402445 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.831402445 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.831402445 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.840339832 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.840339832 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.840339832 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.840339832 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.840339832 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.844512992 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.844512992 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.844512992 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.844512992 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
Apr 01 13:35:36.844512992 generic.com WindowsLog Computer=COMP-user-0001  User=user-0001  TimeGenerated=1523806159   TimeWritten=1523806159
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
lineNo=0
jump=110
while [ "$lineNo" -le 1100 ] && [ "$lineNo" -gt 0 ]
do
        sed -i "${lineNo}s/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{1,2\}\s[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}\:[0-9]\{2\}/$(date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")/g" kk
lineNo=$((lineNo + jump))
done
```

we can do this with single sed command.

- `sed -i "${lineNo}....` will edit the file only in the specified line number which we pass.
- `[ "$lineNo" -gt 0 ]` to ignore the variable to pass the value as ZERO to avoid errors.

Comment: I tried this way and with the check for -gt 0 the script does not run. With that check rmoved the script runs but there is an error when running `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: } doesn't want any addresses`. Im assuming it doesnt like the lineNo variable in the sed command

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3="";$0=strftime("%b %d %H:%M:%S")" "$0;print;if(NR%110){system("sleep 1")}}' filename
```

this will just remove the first three columns and replace with current timestamp. then wait for a second. then update the next 110 line with current timestamp..

Comment: Why the `sleep`? Note that by modifying the first three fields and then printing the record, you will compress the multiple spaces that occurs elsewhere in the data. This also seems to be modifying _every_ line.  Hmm... maybe I misunderstood the question.